# Using regex with jQuery in binding events

Tags: jquery, regex, events, bind

Is it possible to use a regex in jQuery's bind method for custom events. Something like...

```
$(selector).bind(myRegex, function(){})
```

For example, if I have two custom events, `CustomerAdd`, and `CustomerDelete` that can be announced, I'd like to be able to listen for `Customer*`.

Comment: Can you provide an example regex so we can understand what you're trying to achieve? Something like... capture all mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a regex to select only certain DOM elements, you can use the .filter() method to pass in a function that would then perform regex logic to filter out the elements that don't match.

```
$(selector).filter(function (index) {
                  return /myregex/.test($(this).attr("id"));
                })
```

Otherwise it's not too clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: It's not the selector, it's the name of the custom event that I want to use a regex for. For example, if I have two custom events, 'CustomerAdd', and 'CustomerDelete' that can be announced, I'd like to be able to listen for 'Customer*'.